# Residue of $m$-order pole Computation

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having trouble with the following residue computation:

> Find the order of the pole and corresponding residue for $$\bigg(\frac{z}{2z+1}\bigg)^3$$

The solution is given as: order  = $3$ and residue = $-3/16$. I am not getting this residue: what am I doing wrong in the following calculation (I want to use this method to compute)?

Let $f(z) = \frac{\phi(z)}{(2z+1)^3}$ where $\phi(z) = z^3$. $\phi(z)$ is analytic and non-zero at the pole $z=-1/2$ -- which is evidently order 3. One can compute the residue then: $\frac{\phi''(z)}{2!} = \frac{6(-1/2)}{2!} = -3/2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is

$$
f(z) = \bigg(\frac{z}{2z+1}\bigg)^3 = \frac18 \bigg(\frac{z}{z-(-1/2)}\bigg)^3
$$

Hence your residual is, using $\phi(z) = z^3$ and evaluating at $z = -1/2$:
$$
\frac18 \frac{\phi''(z)}{2!} = \frac18 \frac{6(-1/2)}{2!} = -\frac3{16}
$$
You always need to write down the denominator factors as $(z -z_i)^{k_i}$ where $z_i$ are the poles and $k_i$ the order of the poles.